# Powershell compare size of local file to file on sharepoint

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I am using the current code to download a file from a sharepoint...

```
$webClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$webClient.UseDefaultCredentials = $true
$webClient.DownloadFile($sharepointPathFile, $localPathFile) | Out-Null
```

But what if I wanted to check if the file is already at the local location and the size matches or is different? How would I do this using powershell?

## Update

This was the closest I could get...

```
$url = $sharepointPathFile
$clnt = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($url)
$resp = $clnt.GetResponse()
$fileSize = $resp.ContentLength
Write-Host $fileSize
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
Exception calling "GetResponse" with "0" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."
At C:\Scripts\Tests\testCheckUpdatedSearchFiles.ps1:345 char:2
+     $resp = $clnt.GetResponse()
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException
```

I have full read and download rights, so is there something else not going right here?

Comment: Based on your historical activity, I'm guessing you are going to answer your own question in a little bit after actually doing some research on your own...

Comment: Sorry, but it looks like I'm actually stuck this time... I'm really unfimiliar working with sharepoints, and my place is making sure I'm an admin of nothing here (making it difficult to develop scripts).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if the "GetResponse" method will return exactly what you're looking for. And depending on the ContentLength, you may want to explicitly define your types. I would try something like this:

```
$webClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$webClient.OpenRead("path/to/file")
[Int64]$fileSize = $webClient.ResponseHeaders["Content-Length"]
Write-Host $fileSize
```